# How to use the verb 'burst'

Tags: verbs, tenses

If a balloon bursts, then how should I tell about it to another person right after this event occurred?

1. the balloon **has** burst
2. the balloon **had** burst
3. the balloon **has been** burst
4. the balloon **had been** burst
5. the balloon **burst** (simple past)

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: What is the special relevance of *burst* to this question? Why are you facing difficulty just with *burst*?

Comment: @Kris: there are not so many verbs that can be active or passive without changing the meaning: *burst* is a good example, where *blow up*, for example, would mean different things in 1/2 and 3/4.

Comment: @TimLymington Let's understand the OP's situation.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232968/simple-past-vs-present-perfect Please suggest which answer you would chose and explain why. If we know your choice, we might be able to help.

Comment: (1) Did anyone see A bursting the balloon? (2) Did something else happen?  (3) Why haven't you suggested using *just* in any of the options? Is there a reason? (4) Does B asks a question? If yes, what exactly?