# english grammer simple and present perfect

Tags: grammar

Afghanistan always suffered from a political crisis, it is the Americans ..... 
or
Afghanistan has  always suffered from a political crisis, it is the American...   which one is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple past vs. present perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232968/simple-past-vs-present-perfect)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all, there is a comma splice before you say "ït is the Americans..." You can fix this by ending the sentence and putting "it is the Americans..." as a new sentence, or you can replace the comma with a semi colon. Another method is to put a coordinating conjunction, such as and, after the comma.

To answer your question, both sound grammatical, but "has always" seems like it would fit best in this situation.